# Clean up [modulus] and [modulo]

Tags: discussion, retag-request

The [original request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213294/synonymize-modulus-and-modulo) was a synonym request.

However, I would like to restart as a discussion on how to deal with the 2 tags:

- [modulus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/modulus) (around 400 questions)
- [modulo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/modulo) (around 600 questions).

According to the link in [this answer on Mathematis.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/472856/what-is-the-difference-between-modulus-absolute-value-and-modulo), the terms modulus and modulo have been used to refer to [different concepts in mathematics](http://jeff560.tripod.com/m.html).

- [Modular arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) can be referred to by "modulus", "modulo" or "mod". "Modulo" or "mod" invariably (?, as far as I can see from the article) refers to modular arithmetic in mathematics context.
- "Modulus" was assigned to different concepts in mathematics. Among them, the concept of "length of the vector a + bi" is most likely to be asked on SO.

What should be done to these 2 tags? How should we disambiguate them?

Comment: FYI, I cleaned up a few questions that were referencing Modulus, a hosting service for Node.js.  They were moved to the existing tag [modulus.io](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/modulus.io).

Answer (score 1):

This one bothers me. *Modulus* is sometimes used to mean *modulo*, but it is more often used to mean absolute value or norm. The current tag excerpt for [modulus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/modulus) describes *modulo*, and most questions tagged with it are related to the *modulo* operator.

Even if we accept the use to mean *modulo*, it becomes an ambiguous term and therefore should not be used as a tag.

The currently proposed synonimization would convert [modulus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/modulus) into [modulo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/modulo), a very satisfying outcome.

There are currently 3 votes to make these two tags synonymous. Unfortunately I don't have the required 5 score in the tag to vote.

Please help, if you can, by [voting here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/modulo/synonyms)!

As of now:

- [modulo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/modulo): 1,104 questions
- [modulus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/modulus): 729 questions and no tag wiki